# Is this inequality a consequence of strong convexity?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let $V:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ be a **strongly convex**, smooth function. By definition there exists $\alpha>0$ such that
$$x^T \textsf{Hess} V(\xi) x \geq \alpha\,|x|^2$$
for all $x,\xi\in\mathbb R^2$.

$V$ has a unique minimum point: assume it is at $x=0$. As a consequence it is easy to check that
$$ x\cdot \nabla V(x) \geq \alpha\,|x|^2$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R^2$. Just Taylor expand $\nabla V(x)= \textsf{Hess} V(\xi)\,x\,$ for some $\xi\in(0,x)$.

**My question**: assume also that derivatives of $V$ of any order have polynomial growth. Are there $\tilde\alpha>0$ and a non-negative polynomial function $p$ such that
$$ x_1\cdot \partial_1 V(x_1,x_2) \geq \tilde\alpha\,|x_1|^2 - p(|x_2|)$$
for all $x=(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb R^2$?

This seems to me a sort of convexity condition restricted to the first variable only, keeping the second one fixed.
If $V$ is a **polynomial**, the desired inequality is true.
What about the general case? I don't manage to prove it nor to find a counter-example.